# Let Eclipse know files included via -include gcc flag

Tags: c, eclipse, gcc, macros, include

I need to include a configuration header file (config.h), containing system-wise defines.
Instead of including it in every source file, I used the -include gcc flag, like so:

```
-include src/config.h
```

This works as expected, however Eclipse does not know that config.h is indeed included in every source file, so, whenever a block like this is present:

```
#ifdef MACRO_DEFINED_IN_CONFIG_H
// Code block
#endif
```

everything is greyed-out.

Is there a workaround for this? Thank you.

Comment: The workaround is include it in every source file, probably.

Comment: I should have of course added, without including it in every source file ;)

Comment: " Instead of including it in every source file, I used the -include gcc flag"  Don't do that... Write code that functions in any tool chain. Write code which documents all file dependencies to the programmer.

Comment: Okay, it makes sense, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have those definitions in the project properties:

[image]

not in the file. Then eclipse will call the gcc wirh the `-D....`s

Comment: there is no other way in eclipse. It perfectly answers the question

Comment: @P__J__: thank you for the answer, not exactly what I was looking for but still helpful.